# OpenCart - не работает модификация

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

Сделал небольшую тестовую модификацию. Вот мой файл install.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
 <name>Вывод артикула</name>
sku_wfm
 <version>1.0</version>
 <code>dasdasd</code>
 <author>Andrey</author>
 <link>https://webformyself.com </link>
 <file path="catalog/controller/product/category.php">
 <operation>
 <search>
 <![CDATA[if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }]]>
 </search>
 <add position="after">
 <![CDATA[print_r('blablabla');]]>
 </add>
 </operation>
 </file>
</modification>
```

Создал пустую папку upload и файл install.php, где нет ничего, кроме `<?php`

Поместил это все в modname.ocmod.zip. Устанавливаю через инсталлятор из админки, установка проходит успешно, в разделе модификаторов модификация отображается, модификации обновляю, вроде все успешно. Но на самом сайте в разделе Категорий изменений нет. По пути `/system/storage/modification/catalog/controller` по идее должна создаваться папка product, а в ней файл category.php - но их нет. Права на всю папку system и ее потомков для эксперимента установил 0777. Версия OpenCart 3.0.3.1.

Comment: А в логах ошибок нет?

Comment: Связанных с установкой данной модификации ничего нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы ищете несколько строк:

```
<search>
 <![CDATA[if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                    $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
                } else {
                    $rating = false;
                }]]>
 </search>
```

А вы должны искать ОДНУ строку. Потому что `VQMOD` / `OCMOD` ищут только по одной строке. Если вы ищете `if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {`, а добавить код хотите после `}`, то используйте атрибут `offset`. Например:

```
<add position="after" offset="4">
 <![CDATA[print_r('blablabla');]]>
</add>
```

Где `4` сколько "пропустить" строк.

Comment: Спасибо, работает